# Vertical jump and muscle mass

Tags: muscle-mass, vertical-jump

I play basketball and I want to increase my vertical jump but at the moment my arms are still skinny so would I be able to gain muscle mass on my arms as well as get my vertical jump higher?

Answer (score 2):

Considering that [one of the biggest improvements you can make for improving your vertical jump is to get strong](http://msuathletics.ru/books/bible/vert_jump_bible.pdf) (PDF), I'd say there's no problem with gaining upper body muscle mass at the same time as you improve lower body strength. Get started squatting, deadlifting, chin-upping, and dipping.

Answer (score 0):

Muscle mass on your arms will help you create momentum when you throw them up.  Also don't neglect core strength.  You can impart lots of force with your legs,  but go nowhere if your back isn't strong enough to transfer it to your arms, chest,  shoulders and arms.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put to much work into getting your arms big ! The arms serve to give you momentum and create the required balance once you get into the jumping position.
 You have to understand one aspect of the strength training for track & field or speed sports in general. 
 If you are center, yes you will need to get some weight on those arms, if you are a forward the same thing but not to much if you are a pg you don't need strong heavy arms muscles.
 As for jumping purpose just make sure you have good elasticity in your shoulders with a full range of motion.
 Most important when working "arms" in basketball the exercises must be done simulating the game ! - like passing drills with heavy balls or ball awareness drills.
 For the vertical jump once you master the movement of  clean box jump your arm will learn how to create the required momentum, also you can use light rubber bands to simulate the arms jumping extension.